# Fiber channel card without san for testing

Tags: san

I have received a pci-x card HP A6795AX A6795-62001 2G/1Gbps 64bit Single Port PCI Fibre Channel 
is possible to test it without cable connect to san or san switch?
Or i will get error messages?System is HPUX,
i want to test without cable only to see if card work or is broken.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

usual try

```
 ioscan -e -C fc 
 ioscan -fnC fc
```

if 11iV3 `fcinfo` (can't remember syntax)

Comment: I know those commands,but my question was another,a fc card without SAN connected,better..without cable connected will return error messages?Is dangerous for card to connect without cable?

Comment: Not dangerous at all. It just give you fiber statua.

Comment: Put as answer i can vote and close question